# What is the meaning of "boobable" in the next context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the word "boobable"?

I saw it in a policy of car rental in the UK

> "The congestion charge (charge code C ) is only **boobable** at the
>   station"

[image]

I didn't find this word on the dictionaries and I suspect that it is a typo (an then with what word it's confused?), but maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a typo (***boobable*** for ***bookable***).

Comment: I can help you happily to vote to close it but explain me please why it matters (to leave or not to leave it open)?

Comment: It matters because questions like this aren't likely to help future visitors. By which I don't mean to criticise you for *asking* (since you couldn't know it was just a trivial typo or OCR error), but keeping the question open is pointless. I don't understand why someone *upvoted* - but I've just downvoted it myself, and if the option arises in future I'll vote to *delete*. Part of the purpose of ELL is to create a searchable archive of useful questions/answers that should help future visitors, within which context questions about typos are really just unwanted noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only **bookable** [LINK - London Congestion Charge](http://invernessairportcarhire.net/sixt_uk_inverness_airport_brand_info.html)

The congestion charge (charge code C ) is only bookable at the station!